# frames for minted in beamer

Tags: beamer, minted

I ran into a problem of including a `tex` file via `\inputminted` from the [minted package](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted). When I try to add a frame around the code with `frame=single` I get lots of errors referring to missing `$`'s missing `}`'s and missing `\item`'s.

The MWE is a self-referential `tex`-file with the following contents:

```tex
% this is: frames_for_minted_in_beamer.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \inputminted[%
        label=frames_for_minted_in_beamer.tex,%
        % frame=single,% this does not work
    ]{latex}{./frames_for_minted_in_beamer.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What went wrong here?

Ty for any help,
Franz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the special characters you use in the label. Using the `frame=single` style will typeset the label at the top and unescaped math characters like `_` will cause an error.

You can either escape them:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

% this is: frames_for_minted_in_beamer.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \inputminted[%
        label=frames\_for\_minted\_in\_beamer.tex,%
        frame=single,% this does not work
    ]{latex}{test.tex}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

or use the `tcolorbox` package to draw a simple frame without the label:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\tcbset{listing engine=minted,colback=white,sharp corners}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
\tcbinputlisting{minted language=latex,listing file=test.tex,label=test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea why it does not work the way I tried?
I would prefer not to add another package and more code if possible.

Comment: @Franz The underscores in your label cause the problem

Comment: ty. works fine now.